# AngularJS component nesting

Tags: angularjs, angular-components, angularjs-ng-transclude

I created a component search-context, which works well. It's configurable and it does what it's supposed to do.

```
<search-context context-name="Groups"
    compare-columns="['displayName']"
    search-manager="$ctrl"
    query-url="/group/search/{{contextId}}"
    icon="fa fa-users"
    on-resolve-item-url="resolveItemUrl(row)"></search-context>
```

Here it is in action, standalone.

[image: search-context in action, standalone]

There are various other search contexts, and I'd like to create a search-manager component such that I can write markup like this:

```
<search-manager>
    <search-context context-name="Devices"
                    compare-columns="['displayName']"
                    search-manager="$ctrl"
                    query-url="/device/search/{{contextId}}"
                    icon="fa fa-laptop"></search-context>
    <search-context context-name="Groups"
                    compare-columns="['displayName']"
                    search-manager="$ctrl"
                    query-url="/group/search/{{contextId}}"
                    icon="fa fa-users"
                    on-resolve-item-url="resolveGroupEditUrl(row)"></search-context>
</search-manager>
```

The general plan is for search-context to check whether it has a search-manager and if so suppress its own input/button controls, and the search-manager will supply input controls and supply the search term to the search contexts.

The examples in the AngularJS component documentation demonstrate *dynamic* child controls using ng-repeat in the control template, but it's not clear how to set things up to handle explicit markup such as I propose. If at all possible I'd prefer not to need to explicitly specify the `search-manager="$ctrl"` parent reference.

How does one go about this and what are the supporting topics one must research and understand? Just the key concept names would be a big help but an overview and a further-reading list would be awesome.

My first attempt at the template for `search-manager` looks like this

```
<div>
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Search</h3>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input class="form-control" ng-model="$ctrl.term" />
            <span class="input-group-btn" ng-click="$ctrl.search()">
                <button class="btn btn-default">
                    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                </button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <ng-transclude></ng-transclude>
    </div>

</div>
```

The code looks like this

```
function SearchManagerController($scope, $element, $attrs, $http) {
    var ctrl = this;
    ctrl.searchContext = [];
    ctrl.registerSearchContext = function (searchContext) {
        ctrl.searchContext.push(searchContext);
    }
    ctrl.search = function () {
        ctrl.searchContext.forEach(function (searchContext) {
            searchContext.search(ctrl.term);
        });
    };
}
angular.module("app").component("searchManager", {
    templateUrl: "/app/components/search-manager.html",
    controller: SearchManagerController,
    transclude: true,
    bindings: {
        term: "@"
    }
});
```

The child components are transcluded but they need a reference to the `search-manager` component, and `$ctrl` is not in scope.

How do we get a reference to the parent?

Comment: One thing to consider is making use of component callbacks (i.e. those `&` bindings) rather than forwarding a context. The idea here is that any changes that occur within a child component will be known to a parent if it binds to any exposed callbacks. You also avoid leaking any other unnecessary things in the context to children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To obtain a reference to the parent all you need to do is `require` the parent in the `search-context` declaration. The double caret prefix means to search the parents. Single caret starts with the current object which will work but is slightly less efficient. The question mark means don't barf if you can't find it, just return undefined. This is necessary when the component may not always be parented by a search manager.

```
angular.module("app").component("searchContext", {
    templateUrl: "/app/components/search-context.html",
    controller: SearchContextController,
    require: {
        searchManagerCtrl: "?^^searchManager"
    },
    bindings: {
        ...
    }
});
```

But what if you need the parent to have references to the children?

In the `SearchContextController` we implement the `$onInit` lifecycle event handler.

```
    ctrl.$onInit = function () {
        if (ctrl.searchManagerCtrl) {
            ctrl.searchManagerCtrl.registerSearchContext(ctrl);
        }
    };
```

`registerSearchContext` is a method defined in the parent's controller for this purpose. The implementation essentially pushes each registered control into an array property we define on its scope, and then methods of the parent can enumerate the children.

For a directive this `require` trick is expressed slightly differently. You must declare the property `searchManagerCtrl` in the directive scope, and supply the expression directly as the value of require.

```
require: "?^^searchManager",
```

You must also supply a `link` function. One of the parameters of a `link` function is `controller` and a reference to `searchManager` will be passed in this parameter, at which point you can assign it to a property of the directive scope. The `$onInit` lifecycle event is still available for registering with the search manager, but refers to `$scope` rather than `ctrl`.